# Using colons in ConfigParser Python

Tags: python, file, configuration

According to the documentation:

> The configuration file consists of
>   sections, led by a [section] header
>   and followed by name: value entries,
>   with continuations in the style of RFC
>   822 (see section 3.1.1, “LONG HEADER
>   FIELDS”); name=value is also accepted.
>   [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)

However, writing a config file always use the equal sign (=). Is there any option to use the colon sign (:)?

Thanks in advance.

H

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the code defining the `RawConfigParser.write` method inside `ConfigParser.py` you'll see that the equal signs are hard-coded. So to change the behavior you could subclass the ConfigParser you wish to use:

```
import ConfigParser
class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):
    def write(self, fp):
        """Write an .ini-format representation of the configuration state."""
        if self._defaults:
            fp.write("[%s]\n" % DEFAULTSECT)
            for (key, value) in self._defaults.items():
                fp.write("%s : %s\n" % (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
            fp.write("\n")
        for section in self._sections:
            fp.write("[%s]\n" % section)
            for (key, value) in self._sections[section].items():
                if key != "__name__":
                    fp.write("%s : %s\n" %
                             (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
            fp.write("\n")

filename='/tmp/testconfig'    
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    parser=MyConfigParser()
    parser.add_section('test')
    parser.set('test','option','Spam spam spam!')
    parser.set('test','more options',"Really? I can't believe it's not butter!")
    parser.write(f)
```

yields:

```
[test]
more options : Really? I can't believe it's not butter!
option : Spam spam spam!
```

Comment: @user482819 So accept the answer please. In this way we now it doesn't need a solution anymore.