# Python extending with - using super() Python 3 vs Python 2

Tags: python, inheritance, configparser

Originally I wanted to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058400/using-colons-in-configparser-python), but then I found it was already thought of before...

Googling around I found this example of [extending configparser](http://sureshamrita.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/extending-python-configparser/ozn@yenikaro:%7E/Software/). The following works with Python 3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3rc2 (default, Mar 21 2012, 06:59:51) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>>> from configparser import  SafeConfigParser
>>> class AmritaConfigParser(SafeConfigParser):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__()
... 
>>> cfg = AmritaConfigParser()
```

But not with Python 2:

```
>>> class AmritaConfigParser(SafeConfigParser):
...       def __init__(self):
...           super(SafeConfigParser).init()
... 
>>> cfg = AmritaConfigParser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: must be type, not classob
```

Then I read a little bit on Python New Class vs. Old Class styles (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713038/super-fails-with-error-typeerror-argument-1-must-be-type-not-classobj).
And now I am wondering, I can do:

```
class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):
      def Write(self, fp):
          """override the module's original write funcition"""
          ....
      def MyWrite(self, fp):
          """Define new function and inherit all others"""
```

But, shouldn't I call init? Is this in Python 2 the equivalent:

```
 class AmritaConfigParser(ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser):
    #def __init__(self):
    #    super().__init__() # Python3 syntax, or rather, new style class syntax ...
    #
    # is this the equivalent of the above ? 
    def __init__(self):
        ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser.__init__(self)
```

Comment: In your example you don't need to define an `__init__()` in the subclass if all it does is call the super class' `__init__()` (in either Python 2 or 3) -- instead just let the super's be inherited.

Comment: Useful reference with corrected link: http://amyboyle.ninja/Python-Inheritance

Answer (score 200, accepted):

- [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super) (without arguments) was introduced in Python 3 (along with `__class__`):

  ```
  super() -> same as super(__class__, self)
  ```

  so that would be the Python 2 equivalent for new-style classes:

  ```
  super(CurrentClass, self)
  ```
- for old-style classes you can always use:

  ```
   class Classname(OldStyleParent):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          OldStyleParent.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  ```

Comment: -1. This answer didn't clarify anything for me. In Python 2, `super(__class__)` gives `NameError: global name '__class__' is not defined`, and `super(self.__class__)` is erroneous as well. You *must* provide an instance as a second argument, which would suggest you need to do `super(self.__class__, self)`, but that is **wrong**. If `Class2` inherits from `Class1` and `Class1` calls `super(self.__class__, self).__init__()`, `Class1`'s `__init__` will then *call itself* when instantiating an instance of `Class2`.

Comment: To clarify a point, I get `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` when trying to call `super(self.__class__)` in Python 2. (Which doesn't make a lot of sense, but it demonstrates how much information is missing from this answer.)

Comment: @jpmc26: in python2 you get this error because your trying to call `__init__()` without argument on the unbound super object (which you get by calling `super(self.__class__)` with only one argument), you need a bound super object then it should work: `super(CurrentClass, self).__init__()`. Don't use `self.__class__` because that will always refer to the _same_ class when calling a parent and therfore create an infinite loop if that parent also does the same.

Comment: `__class__` (member) also exists in *Python2*.

Comment: @CristiFati This isn't about the `__class__` member but about the [implicitly created lexical `__class__` closure](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) which always refers to the class currently being defined, which doesn't exist in python2.

Answer (score 64):

In a single inheritance case (when you subclass one class only), your new class inherits methods of the base class. This includes `__init__`. So if you don't define it in your class, you will get the one from the base.

Things start being complicated if you introduce multiple inheritance (subclassing more than one class at a time). This is because if more than one base class has `__init__`, your class will inherit the first one only.

In such cases, you should really use `super` if you can, I'll explain why. But not always you can. The problem is that all your base classes must also use it (and their base classes as well -- the whole tree).

If that is the case, then this will also work correctly (in Python 3 but you could rework it into Python 2 -- it also has `super`):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')
        super().__init__()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')
        super().__init__()

class C(A, B):
    pass

C()
#prints:
#A
#B
```

Notice how both base classes use `super` even though they don't have their own base classes.

What `super` does is: it calls the method from the next class in MRO (method resolution order). The MRO for `C` is: `(C, A, B, object)`. You can print `C.__mro__` to see it.

So, `C` inherits `__init__` from `A` and `super` in `A.__init__` calls `B.__init__` (`B` follows `A` in MRO).

So by doing nothing in `C`, you end up calling both, which is what you want.

Now if you were not using `super`, you would end up inheriting `A.__init__` (as before) but this time there's nothing that would call `B.__init__` for you.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')

class C(A, B):
    pass

C()
#prints:
#A
```

To fix that you have to define `C.__init__`:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
```

The problem with that is that in more complicated MI trees, `__init__` methods of some classes may end up being called more than once whereas super/MRO guarantee that they're called just once.

Comment: `Notice how both base classes use super even though they don't have their own base classes.` They have. In py3k every class subclasses object.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, but didn't know how to ask.  The MRO description is good.

Answer (score 31):

In short, they are equivalent. 
Let's have a history view:

(1) at first, the function looks like this.

```
    class MySubClass(MySuperClass):
        def __init__(self):
            MySuperClass.__init__(self)
```

(2) to make code more abstract (and more portable). A common method to get Super-Class is invented like:

```
    super(<class>, <instance>)
```

And init function can be:

```
    class MySubClassBetter(MySuperClass):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MySubClassBetter, self).__init__()
```

However  requiring an explicit passing of both the class and instance break the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) rule a bit.

(3) in V3. It is more smart,

```
    super()
```

is enough in most case. You can refer to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/

Answer (score 24):

Just to have a simple and complete example for Python 3, which most people seem to be using now.

```
class MySuper(object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

class MySub(MySuper):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(a)

my_sub = MySub(42,'chickenman')
print(my_sub.a)
print(my_sub.b)
```

gives

```
42
chickenman
```

Answer (score 4):

Another python3 implementation that involves the use of Abstract classes with super(). You should remember that

```
super().__init__(name, 10)
```

has the same effect as

```
Person.__init__(self, name, 10)
```

Remember there's a hidden 'self' in super(), So the same object passes on to the superclass init method and the attributes are added to the object that called it. 
Hence `super()`gets translated to  `Person` and then if you include the hidden self, you get the above code frag.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Person(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    name = ""
    age = 0

    def __init__(self, personName, personAge):
        self.name = personName
        self.age = personAge

    @abstractmethod
    def showName(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def showAge(self):
        pass


class Man(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, height):
        self.height = height
        # Person.__init__(self, name, 10)
        super().__init__(name, 10)  # same as Person.__init__(self, name, 10)
        # basically used to call the superclass init . This is used incase you want to call subclass init
        # and then also call superclass's init.
        # Since there's a hidden self in the super's parameters, when it's is called,
        # the superclasses attributes are a part of the same object that was sent out in the super() method

    def showIdentity(self):
        return self.name, self.age, self.height

    def showName(self):
        pass

    def showAge(self):
        pass


a = Man("piyush", "179")
print(a.showIdentity())
```