# python super() function error?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
class car(object):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

class electricCar(car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)

tesla = electricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print tesla.get_descriptive_name()
```

> TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

what is the problem with the super() function ?

Comment: replace `super()` by the name of your superclass, i. e. `car`. Or if you want `super`, `super(electricCar, self).__init__(make, model, year)`

Comment: What version of Python are you using? You can see the `super()` syntax in [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) . For Python 2 you need to specify the child class name as the type argument. For Python3 you don't

Comment: If you are just learning the language... why are you starting with a python version that is *6 years old*? Just start with the newest versions. Python2 should be used only by people who need it for backwards compatibility with old systems/libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`super()` (without arguments) was introduced in ***python3***
 Here is   ***python2*** implementation.

```
class electricCar(car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super(electricCar,self).__init__(make, model, year)
```

you could refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482953/python-extending-with-using-super-python-3-vs-python-2) for general inheritance syntax issue regarding *python2* and *python3*

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to use the Python 3 syntax, but you are using Python 2. In that version you need to pass the current class and instance as arguments to the `super` function:

```
super(electricCar, self).__init__(make, model, year)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2 you need to pass your instance explicitly with the super method. In python 3 or higher, instance variable are passed implicitly you don't need to specify it. Here `self` is an instance of the class `car`

```
super(car, self).__init__(make, model, year)
```