# Initialize different classes in a similar way

Tags: class, object, initialization, python-3.5

I have different Classes which I need to initialize partially in almost the same way. The init function takes in input a file path and/or some numpy data.

```
class InertialData1:
   def __init__(self, file=None, data=None):
      # --- this is the (almost) common part ---
      if file is None:
        self.file = 'Unknown path to file'
      else:
        self.file = file
      assert isinstance(self.file, str)

      if data is None:
        self.data = read_logfile(file, 'a_token')
      else:
        self.data = data
      assert isinstance(self.data, np.ndarray)
      # --- end of the common part ---

      # Here other stuff different from class to class
```

The token in the read_logfile() function (an external function) also changes from class to class.

```
class InertialData2:
   def __init__(self, file=None, data=None):
      # here the common code as above, but with 'another_token' instead of 'a_token'
      # here other stuff
...
```

Writing the same lines in all the classes definition is a no go, of course.

Possible solution.

I thought about defining an external function like this

```
def initialize(file, data, token):
    if file is None:
        file = 'Unknown path to file'
    else:
        file = file
    assert isinstance(file, str)

    if data is None:
        data = read_logfile(file, token)
    else:
        data = data
    assert isinstance(data, np.ndarray)
return file, data
```

Then I could use it inside the **init** method of each class like this:

```
class InertialData1:
   def __init__(self, file=None, data=None):
        self.file = file
        self.data = data
        self.file, self.data = initialize(self.file, self.data, token='a_token')
```

This way seems to be working. I just have the feeling it is not the best way of doing it, or not pythonic, and I hope to learn something from your answers :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) up your code by using class inheritance:

```
class InertialData:
  def __init__(self, file=None, data=None):
    # --- this is the common part ---
    if file is None:
      self.file = 'Unknown path to file'
    else:
      self.file = file
    assert isinstance(self.file, str)

  def init_data(self, token, data):
    if data is None:
      self.data = read_logfile(self.file, token)
    else:
      self.data = data
    assert isinstance(self.data, np.ndarray)

class InertialData1(InertialData):
  def __init__(self, file=None, data=None):
    # --- this is the different part ---
    super().__init__(file=file, data=data);
    self.init_data('token_a', data)
```

Notice a few things:

You can make a "common" class, InertialData, that has the repeated functionality. Then All of your custom classes can inherit from the common one. See how the class `InertialData1` takes `InertialData` as a parameter?

In all classes that inherit from `InertialData`, you can call `super` and this will call the `__init__` method of the superclass, which in this case is `InertialData`.

The bit of code that initializes the data that has the differing token for each class has been pulled into a function that takes the token as a parameter. Now you can call `initialize_data('token_a')` in the `__init__` function of any class that inherits from `InertialData`.

I renamed your classes to begin with capital letters (as is Python's convention).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However it doesn't seem to work like this.

TypeError: super does not take keyword arguments

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that `super` automatically reuses the arguments that are passed in. I also realized that you will need to pass `data` into the `init_data` method, so I added that code too

Comment: `super` alone is also not working. 
`super().__init__(file, data)` is working.

However, I'm unsure it's a good practice to call the base init function like this.

Comment: I see my mistake now. I was calling super like you do in the language Ruby... Yes, it is conventional to use `super().__init__()` in python 3. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482953/python-extending-with-using-super-python-3-vs-python-2) answer. You will still want to use your keyword arguments though. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Robyc, does this solution seem better now?