# super() in tkinter application

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, super

I am having trouble understanding this error.

In the below code,when I use `tk.Frame` everything works as intended. However if I use `super()`, I get thrown an `AttributeError` ('*Application object has no attribute tk*').

```py
class Application(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self,parent):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) <----- This works
       # super().__init__(self,parent) <------ This line throws an error
.
.
.

if __name__=='main':
  root=tk.Tk()
  Application(root).pack()
  root.mainloop()
```

It is my understanding that `super(Application,self).__init__()` will call the the `__init__` method that is bounded to the class followed by `child` in the instance's MRO, which is, the class `tkinter.Frame` in my situation.

I verified this by printing out `Application.__mro__` and checking.

So my question if both `super().__init__(self,parent)` and `tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)` are referring to the same `__init__` method of class `tkinter.Frame`, why is one throwing an error and the other working fine? I suspect I have some misunderstanding in the way super() works.

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` when calling super.

Comment: @HenryYik That solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 `super` does not require to pass `self` as an argument.

The following example illustrates the correct way to call `super` to initialize the parent class of a widget:

```
import tkinter as tk 


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        tk.Button(self, text='Super!', command=root.destroy).pack()


root = tk.Tk()
Application(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The reason is that the python core developers decided to simplify the use of `super`, and abstracted the passing of `self` to the underlying code that powers python.
[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482953/python-extending-with-using-super-python-3-vs-python-2)