# Need help an error "TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given"

Tags: python, class, object, pygame

I am just started getting into classes and understand the basic concept however I don't understand why it gives me this error.

My code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False

while not done:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        class shape():
            def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y):
                self.place = place
                self.colour = colour
                self.x = x
                self.y = y

        class rectangle(shape):
            def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y, length, width):
                super().__init__(self, place, colour, x, y)

                self.length = length
                self.width = width

                pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, pygame.Rect(x, y, lenght, width))





        Rectangle = rectangle(screen, (0, 128, 255), 30, 30, 60, 60)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

The error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pygame.py", line 34, in <module>
    Rectangle = rectangle(screen, (0, 128, 255), 30, 30, 60, 60)
  File "Pygame.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, place, colour, x, y)
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

I am not sure why it gives an error as I am creating a "rectangle" object. I found some examples and they seemed to be the same as mine.

Comment: try removing the self from super().__init__()

Comment: `super().__init__(place, colour, x, y)` rather than `super().__init__(self, place, colour, x, y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) returns a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent.
So it has to be:

<s>`super().__init__(self, place, colour, x, y)`</s>

```py
super().__init__(place, colour, x, y)
```

The call is like calling an instance [method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) .

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `super().__init__(self, place, colour, x, y)`.

You are trying to call the initializer of a class you extends, but your `rectangle` class is not extending any class, this means that the `super()` is looking for something builtin class you don't have control over it.

Since you said you took this from an example, my guess is that you are missing to extend a class.

To make the script working you can remove the call to `super().__init__...`

Comment: `shape` is a base class of `rectangle`. The declaration is `class rectangle(shape):`

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue , iam using python 2.7.x. I resolved it using classname directly. Here is the explination [Python extending with - using super() Python 3 vs Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482953/python-extending-with-using-super-python-3-vs-python-2)
Try this

```
shape.__init_(self,place, colour, x, y)
```