# Python 3 - __init__() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make linked_lists in python for the first time but my append function doesn't seem to work properly. Here's the code so far:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, Name = None, Contact_number = None, Type = None, Urgency = None):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Contact_number = Contact_number
        self.Type = Type
        self.Urgency = Urgency
        self.next = None

class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = node()
    
    def append(self, Name, Contact_number, Type, Urgency):
        new_node = node(self,Name,Contact_number,Type,Urgency)
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next != None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = new_node
    
    def length(self):
        cur = self.head()
        total = 0
        while cur.next != None:
            total+=1
            cur=cur.next
        return total
    
    def display(self):
        Appointments = []
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next != None:
            cur_node = cur_node.next
            aptmnt = (cur_node.Name, cur_node.Contact_number, cur_node.Type, cur_node.Urgency)
            Appointments.append(aptmnt)
        print(Appointments)
    
    
general_surgeon = linked_list()
general_surgeon.display()

general_surgeon.append("Akash", "827xxxxxx1", "Min Surgery", "no")
```

And here's the error I get when trying to use the append function :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-0ffb4f93a9c0> in <module>
     39 general_surgeon.display()
     40 
---> 41 general_surgeon.append("Akash", "827xxxxxx1", "Min Surgery", "no")

<ipython-input-27-0ffb4f93a9c0> in append(self, Name, Contact_number, Type, Urgency)
     12 
     13     def append(self, Name, Contact_number, Type, Urgency):
---> 14         new_node = node(self,Name,Contact_number,Type,Urgency)
     15         cur = self.head
     16         while cur.next != None:

TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

I've been copying the basic structure and functions of the linked list directly off of a youtube video and notice no difference between my code and his, apart from mine having more data variables.

Please help?

Comment: When you write `new_node = node(self,Name,Contact_number,Type,Urgency)`, in your own words, why do you include `self` here? What are you expecting the value of `self` to be, and how does it help you to create a `node`?

Comment: Hint: notice how, at the top level, you wrote `general_surgeon = linked_list()`. This is **correct**. Notice that you did **not** write `general_surgeon = linked_list(self)` (which would be incorrect). Think carefully about **why**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help an error "TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973743/need-help-an-error-typeerror-init-takes-5-positional-arguments-but-6-wer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def append(self, Name, Contact_number, Type, Urgency):
    new_node = node(self,Name,Contact_number,Type,Urgency)
```

Since you're calling the `node` class, you don't need to pass the `self` parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I kept overlooking this line of code for whatever reason. This fixed it.

Comment: If this solves your purpose, consider marking it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error, which is already showing as a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

So you are giving 6 arguments rather then 5 in the `line # 14`

No need to pass `self` as an argument in the `node class` at `line # 14`

Try with this:

```
def append(self, Name, Contact_number, Type, Urgency):
    new_node = node(Name, Contact_number, Type, Urgency)
    cur = self.head
    while cur.next != None:
        cur = cur.next
    cur.next = new_node
```

Comment: Please add how to solve the error as well

Comment: add the correction of the method