# Can't init child class with overloaded __init__ method in Ren'Py python code section

Tags: python, oop, renpy

In Ren'Pys python section I've tried to do following:

```
python:
    class test_class0():
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.test0 = kwargs['test0']


    class test_class1(test_class0):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.test1 = kwargs['test1']

    test_obj0 =  test_class0(test0 = 0)
    test_obj1 =  test_class1(test1 = 1, test0 = 0)
```

This works fine for standalone Python, but with Ren'Py I've got following traceback:

```
While running game code:
  File "script.rpy", line 62, in script
    python:
  File "script.rpy", line 75, in <module>
    test_obj1 =  test_class1(test1 = 1, test0 = 0)
  File "script.rpy", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because Ren'Py apparently uses Python 2, where `super` worked differently than in Python 3 (see [Python extending with - using super() Python 3 vs Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482953/python-extending-with-using-super-python-3-vs-python-2)).

It seems that support for Python 3 was added in Ren'Py version [8.0.0](https://www.renpy.org/release/8.0.0), which was released on June 26, 2022, so I suggest upgrading.

Comment: Updtaing to 8.0.4 helped me. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're on a Ren'Py release that uses Python 2. You need to update to the 8.x Ren'Py line.